# how to show GUI of ns2?

Tags: 12.04, networking, command-line, ns2

I have installed NS2 (network simulator 2.34) on my ubuntu 12.4. But when I execute the `ns ns-simple.tcl` in the terminal only the following messages have been shown without any GUI or schematic of my network:

> CBR packet size = 1000 CBR interval = 0.0080000000000000002 ns:
>   finish: couldn't execute "nam": no such file or directory
>       while executing "exec nam out.nam &"
>       (procedure "finish" line 7)
>       invoked from within "finish"

but I want to use it's GUI, Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally could solve my problem haha!!!
the problem was the `nam` package, It must be installed to show the GUI, I installed it by:
`apt-get install nam`
After this installation every thing will be okay
screenshot:
[image]